# What are the advantages of using a Java + Spring + Cucumber framework over a core Java + Cucumber framework in testing?

Tags: java, spring, testing, automated-tests, cucumber

I've been using a core Java + Cucumber framework in testing for both Web & API testing for years; over the years I've seen a number of people using a Spring Boot + Cucumber framework. I want to understand what are the major advantages of using a Spring Boot framework for an automated testing framework? Could someone explain or point me to already written resources on this topic?

Comment: **Neither** of those stacks you mentioned is a full testing suite. You need something like JUnit on top of that. Spring Boot Test is for full integration tests, it will spin up the entire application.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I use TestNg or Junit along with rest-assured & selenium

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot is going to handle dependencies. It's going to bring all your test and development artifacts through boot-starters. It's nothing to do with Spring Boot for handling test automation.

Spring frameworks has its own advantages of writing tests. With the help of `cucumber-spring` test cases can be enriched in cucumber way.

Quick link to understand Spring and Cucumber - https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/04/webinar-replay-spring-with-cucumber-for-automation

Comment: that's a really old article